# high mysqld cpu usage after moving to new server

Tags: centos, mysql, cpu-usage, top, high-load

Just moved to a new (more powerful) server with only one website running on it, no changes on the website, but now I got a horrible high CPU load and I can't find out why.

top:

```
top - 22:54:08 up 1 day,  3:08,  1 user,  load average: 4.19, 3.66, 3.60
Tasks: 425 total,   1 running, 424 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 22.4%us,  5.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 71.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  49422228k total, 12798552k used, 36623676k free,   582432k buffers
Swap:  1048568k total,        0k used,  1048568k free,  9841796k cached


  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
27557 mysql     20   0 1913m  63m 6928 S 504.9  0.1 648:25.57 mysqld
```

When doing the **strace -p < PID >**, I'm getting following results, but it says nothing to me since I never used strace before:

```
select(13, [10 12], NULL, NULL, NULL)   = 1 (in [12])
fcntl(12, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = 0
accept(12, {sa_family=AF_FILE, NULL}, [2]) = 73
fcntl(12, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)              = 0
getsockname(73, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/lib/mysql\1"}, [28]) = 0
fcntl(73, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY)            = 0
fcntl(73, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(73, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = 0
setsockopt(73, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, [8], 4)  = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
gettimeofday({1399667305, 899867}, NULL) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7f19a819ff10, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f19a81a09d0, tls=0x7f19a81a0700, child_tidptr=0x7f19a81a09d0) = 23139
```

**iotop** is giving me a high kjournal:

```
  432 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    7.47 K/s  0.00 %  7.30 % [kjournald]
```

Do you see something in there? Can you tell me where I could have a look as well to find the source of the problem? Could it have something to do with the Raid-10 I have now?

Comment: Are you actually experiencing any problems?  If your bottleneck before was disk i/o, it's perfectly feasible that MySQL can get more done on the new more powerful hardware which may lead to higher cpu usage.

Comment: show the results of mysqls `show processlist`

Comment: @MatthewIfe  sorry, how to use 'show processlist' from shell with user and password?

Comment: @yoonix Yes, the website is very slow, even with less visitors on the website than before on the old server.

Comment: What are the contents of my.cnf?